# Exception handling for an existing application without having a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement exception handling for all unhandled exceptions for an existing application. I do not have a master page for this application.

I do not want to add the reference for exception handling in each and every page as there are many pages in the application.

Is there a generic way so that I can implement exception handling for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that you could use the [Application.Error event in global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Can you please advise, how I can handle server level errors using this event?

Comment: Have you read the msdn documentation on the link? It is pretty clear in my opinion. Anyway for specific page errors that need to be handled on that page I will handle them accordingly.